# Draw circle on map in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

How to draw circle on map in touch of mapview in titanium for android developer

```
var lat = 23.027608;
var lng = 72.551994;

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lng, lat);
var latlng  = new g
// 200km radius
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
radius : 200 * 1000,
center : latlng
});
circle.setCenter(map.getCenter());
circle.setMap(map); var lat = 23.027608;
var lng = 72.551994;

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lng, lat);
var latlng  = new g
// 200km radius
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
radius : 200 * 1000,
center : latlng
});
circle.setCenter(map.getCenter());
circle.setMap(map);
```

show error on not found google

Answer (score 0):

That sample code isn't from Titanium (it looks rather nothing like Titanium code, actually).

Your question is freely answered by the documentation.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.Map